# dplyr: Replace multiple values based on condition in a selection of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I try to conditionally replace multiple values in a data frame.

In the following data set, I want to replace in columns 3:5 all values of 2 by "X" and all values of 3 by "Y", but only for measure == "led"

condition: measure == "led"
replace: value "2" by "X" and value "3" by "Y" (in columns 3:5)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(measure = sample(c('cfl', 'led', 'linear', 'exit'), 20, replace=T),
                 site = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T),
                 space = sample(1:4, 20, replace=T),
                 qty = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T),
                 qty.exit = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T),
                 cf = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T))
```

Is there a simple dplyr solution for that? Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you tagging the question with dplyr and tidyverse but use data.table in the example? Furthermore, column type must be the same for all elements. You can't replace a number `2` with a character `"Y"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  mutate(across(3:5, ~ ifelse(measure == "led", stringr::str_replace_all(
    as.character(.),
    c("2" = "X", "3" = "Y")
  ), .)))
```

Result:

```
   measure site space qty qty.exit cf
 1:     led    4     1   4        6  3
 2:    exit    4     2   1        4  6
 3:     cfl    1     4   6        2  3
 4:  linear    3     4   1        3  5
 5:     cfl    5     1   6        1  6
 6:    exit    4     3   2        6  4
 7:    exit    5     1   4        2  5
 8:    exit    1     4   3        6  4
 9:  linear    3     1   5        4  1
10:     led    4     1   1        1  1
11:    exit    5     4   3        5  2
12:     cfl    4     2   4        5  5
13:     led    4     X   Y        Y  4
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a data.table solution using a *look-up table* and an *update join*.

As mentioned in [danlooo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109250/dplyr-replace-multiple-values-based-on-condition-in-a-selection-of-columns#comment127410437_72109250), all elements of a column must have the same type. So, it is necessary to coerce all numbers to type character before joining.

```
library(data.table)
# create look-up table
lut <- fread(
  "measure, old, new
  led,      2,   X
  led,      3,   Y",
  colClasses = c(old = "character")
)
# perform coersion and update join for each column
for(col in colnames(dt)[3:5]) {
  set(dt, , col, as.character(dt[[col]]))
  dt[lut, on = c("measure", paste0(col, "==old")), (col) := new][]
}
dt
```

> ```
>     measure site space qty qty.exit cf
>  1:     cfl    3     4   4        3  3
>  2:     cfl    1     2   3        5  5
>  3:     cfl    1     2   6        5  5
>  4:     cfl    3     1   5        4  6
>  5:     led    4     4   X        6  3
>  6:    exit    5     1   6        5  6
>  7:     led    5     4   X        4  4
>  8:     led    5     X   X        6  5
>  9:     cfl    4     4   5        2  1
> 10:    exit    2     2   1        2  4
> 11:  linear    4     3   1        1  1
> 12:    exit    3     4   4        2  1
> 13:  linear    2     3   5        5  5
> 14:    exit    1     1   2        6  6
> 15:     cfl    2     1   1        5  3
> 16:     cfl    6     2   5        4  1
> 17:     led    3     X   4        1  2
> 18:    exit    6     2   4        4  5
> 19:     led    2     X   1        X  6
> 20:     led    4     X   Y        X  1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42) # required for reproducible data
dt <- data.table(measure = sample(c('cfl', 'led', 'linear', 'exit'), 20, replace=T),
                 site = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T),
                 space = sample(1:4, 20, replace=T),
                 qty = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T),
                 qty.exit = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T),
                 cf = sample(1:6, 20, replace=T))
```